# jquery ajax is being called 6 times on single click

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

using c#, mvc 5 here's my client side's code for ajax call:

```
function addEventListener()
    {
        //used this as well to unbind the events but didn't work
        //$('#createNotification').unbind().bind('click', function (e) {
        $('#createNotification').bind('click', function (e) {
            if($('#form').valid())
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Create","Notification")',
                    data: {
                        Title: $('#notifTitle').val(),
                        Message: $('#notifContent').val()
                    },
                    type:'POST',
                    success: function(dt)
                    {
                        // did not fix the problem
                        //$('#createNotification').unbind('click');
                        alert('arash');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

and here's my .ready code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                Title: {
                    required: true
                },
                Message: {
                    required: true
                }
            }
        });
        addEventListener();
    })
```

after clicking on the button the event is fired 6 times and I get 6 alerts, I've searched SO and tried many of the solutions but none worked for me. I'm really lost here because the call should happen once only but it doesn't.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the document.ready only fires once? Could you add some alert or logging in the addEventListener function to be sure this only registers once?

Comment: @codemonkey I've checked and it's only called once

Comment: Check how many times is addEventListener called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of jQuery [validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/):

> submitHandler (default: native form submit)
>
> Type: Function() Callback
> for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form
> as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. **The right place to**
> **submit a form via Ajax after it is validated.**

Try to make this changes and let us know if the problem is solved:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                Title: {
                    required: true
                },
                Message: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            submitHandler: addEventListener
   });

   function addEventListener() {
      $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Create","Notification")',
            data: {
                Title: $('#notifTitle').val(),
                Message: $('#notifContent').val()
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (dt) {
                // did not fix the problem
                //$('#createNotification').unbind('click');
                alert('arash');
            }
        });
  }
});
```

Working example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bf28L5kg/2/)

Comment: It worked and now it's working as it's supposed to do, I wasn't aware of this submit handler to handle the submit event via ajax. thanks again mate